# Using ASP.Net Core Identity and Azure authentication together in Blazor

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, blazor, identity

I have a server-side Blazor app which is successfully integrated with Azure for authentication.  The standard approach worked here, I modified Startup.cs as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized 
                // according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
```

And then I check for authentication in MainLayout.razor as follows:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user = authState.User;
        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity userIdent = user.Identity;
        if (userIdent.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            doMoreStuff(user);
        }
        ...
    }
```

I would like to ALSO enable authorization via Identity with custom UserStore and RoleStore implementations (NOT using Entity framework core).  I started to implement user store and role store, and added them to Startup.cs:

```
IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();            
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserStore<>).MakeGenericType(builder.UserType), typeof(MyUserManager));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRoleStore<>).MakeGenericType(builder.RoleType), typeof(MyRoleManager));
```

But as soon as I add these custom Identity additions, I immediately see the code in MainLayout calling AuthorizationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() now returns null.

Any suggestions on how to implement BOTH custom Identity AND the Azure authentication?  They don't want to play well together for me.

Comment: p.s. can't you just do somehting like `services.AddScoped<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserManager>();`?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I've played more and it turns out one solution is to avoid the services.AddIdentity() method call altogether... in this scenario I manually add my app Claims (Roles, etc.) to the Principal once the Azure GetAuthenticationStateAsync() completes successfully.  In that case, I can just add only the scoped Stores as needed.  Thanks for taking time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question, actually I found some good advice [here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-asp-net-core-authorization-six-months-on/).

The approach seems to be to just take the ClaimsPrincipal returned by Azure, and then add your own additional Claims from within the app.

Comment: The reformed programmer is a good blog to follow by the way. He knows his stuff.